# pdftk: cannot view pdf file

Tags: pdftk

I am trying to view/edit a pdf file in pdftk, and I get the following error:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~/Downloads$ pdftk file.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

What am I doing wrong? Whether or not pdftk can provide a GUI, I just want to view the file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great many solutions for this. @Acorbe is correct that `okular` is one such solution. If you're looking for something lighter-weight, you may also want to take a look at [`zathura`](http://pwmt.org/zathura). Or, if all you want to do is see the text contents (in a similar layout, but not exactly the same), you can also just open the PDF with `vim`. By default, what vim will show you is this stripped-down text-only view.

Either way, pdftk is powerful for command-line usage (as Acorbe mentioned) but does not offer a way to view the resulting file (not that I know of anyway).

Answer (score 2):

`pdftk` is used to do command line-like manipulation of pdf documents (merge/split/...). You can use the help for the syntax.

On the other hand, you can visualize the content of the pdf e.g. with okular

```
$ okular file.pdf
```

.